# Is it possible to change order of operators in Julia?

Tags: julia

I like to change the order of `&` programmatically. Is it possible? for example `3 < 4 & 1 < 4`, `&` is evaluated first, but I like it be evaluated last.

Comment: `(3 < 4) & (1 < 4)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the precedence of `&` - precedence is resolved at parse time in Julia. Do either what Colin T Bowers suggested or use `&&` which has a lower precedence than comparison operators.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is possible if you define an operator with lower precedence than `&` and give it the meaning of `&`.

```
julia> ↺(a,b) = a & b
↺ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> 3 < 4 ↺ 1 < 4
true
```

This is of course some kind of "cheating" and it will make writing other pieces of code with `↺` awkward because it has now the same precedence level as the `=>` operator.

The list of available operators along with their precedence can be found at:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/src/julia-parser.scm